# Eclipse RCP: building product with feature that requires other features

Tags: eclipse-rcp, product

I need to build a product that contains one feature, I want this feature, containing application, requires another feature that can be updated independently from product, so I put this last one in required section and not in included section.

the tree is this:

it.prodotto (product id)
it.rcp.prototipo.application.feature (main feature included in product and containing application)
it.rcp.framework.feature (feature required by main feature)

My problem is this, even if I have these features (and relatively plugins) in my target, when I export my product using eclipse wizard from .product I got this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: prototipo application 1.0.7 (it.prodotto 1.0.7)
 Missing requirement: My Application 1.0.4 (it.rcp.prototipo.application.feature.feature.group 1.0.4) requires 'it.rcp.framework.feature.feature.group 1.0.4' but it could not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
```

I don't understand where (and how) I have to put this features before export the product

I also tried to put this required feature in the same folder where I export the product without success (I tried both launchingfolder  and repository)

I'm using Eclipse Helios 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

The feature `it.rcp.framework.feature` must be added to the product configuration as well.